# Auto open .vcf file on mobile phone - VUE JS & Apache

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apache, web, vcf-vcard

Sir,

I would like to know how to automatically open a .vcf file to record a telephone contact.

Like for example this link:

https://admin.wemet.fr/publicapi/profile/17d0ed45bfd7d0c85571790479cf1a3d/vCard

As soon as you click, it opens a contact to save on your mobile phone.

Here is my link: https://www.skyple.com/nfc/P31I20Z395566

but when i click on my vcard, instead of opening it, it downloads the file.
My need is for the .vcf file to open directly on the add contact app and not to download the .vcf file on mobile phone
I try to add this line in the .htaccess file :

## MIME TYPES

AddType text/x-vcard vcf
AddType application/octet-stream vcf

But still not work

Below, the script :

```
<script>
import useValidate from "@vuelidate/core";
import { required, integer, email, minLength, maxLength } from "@vuelidate/validators";
import { reactive, computed } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
// import Header from './Header'
// import Footer from './Footer'

export default {
  name: "FreeURL",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  components: {
    // Header,
    // Footer
  },
  data() {
    return {
      translate:[],
      errors: [],
      success: [],
      orders: [],
      modules: [],
      module_details: [],
      form: {
        
        module_name1: "",

        staff_phone: null,
        staff_email: null,
        staff_add: null,

        pro_business:null,
        pro_title:null,
        pro_function:null,
        pro_address:null,
        pro_email:null,
        pro_phone:null,
        pro_website:null,

        image: null,
        type: 'WORK',
        notes: null,
        
        // prefix: null,
        // company: null,
        // designation: null,
        // role: null,
        // site: null,
        // address_line_1: null,
        // address_line_2: null,
        // street: null,
        // worktown: null,
        // zip_code: null,
        // country: null,
        

        // first_name: '',
        // last_name: '',
        // suffix: '',
        // email: '',
        // phone: '',
        // dob: ''
      },
      form_append:{
        module_title: "",

        staff_phone: '',
        staff_email: '',
        staff_add: '',

        pro_business:'',
        pro_title:'',
        pro_function:'',
        pro_address:'',
        pro_email:'',
        pro_phone:'',
        pro_website:'',

        image: '',
        type: 'WORK',
        notes: '',

        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        suffix: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        dob: '',
      },
      arr: [],
      before_div: true,
      after_div: false,
      contact_div: false,
      staff_div: false,
      profesional_div: false,
      picture_div: false,
      further_div: false,
      loader_value:false
    };
  },
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      suffix: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      dob: '',
    });
    const rules = computed(() => {
      return {
        first_name: { required },
        last_name: { required },
        suffix: { required },
        email: { required, email },
        phone: { required, integer, minLength: minLength(10), maxLength: maxLength(13)  },
        dob: { required },
      };
    });

    const v$ = useValidate(rules, state);

    return { state, v$ };
  },
  methods: {
    datepick(){
      document.getElementById('maxdate').max = new Date(new Date().getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().split("T")[0];
    },

    toValidate(num)
    {
      // alert(this.state.first_name)
      // alert(this.state.last_name)
      // alert(this.state.email)
      // alert(this.state.phone)
      // alert( this.state.dob)
      // alert(this.state.suffix)
      this.v$.$validate();
      // alert("before if")
      if(num == 1){
        if (!this.v$.$error) {
        if(num==1){
          this.contact_div = false
          this.after_div = true
          console.log("sankha");
          // alert("done")
        }
        else{
          return
        }
      }

      }
       else {
        if(num==2){
          this.staff_div = false
          this.after_div = true
        }
        else if(num==3){
          this.profesional_div = false
          this.after_div = true
        }
        else if(num==4){
          this.picture_div = false
          this.after_div = true
        }
        else if(num==5){
          this.further_div = false
          this.after_div = true
        }
        // alert("else")
        return
      }
    },

    toInstall() {
      this.v$.$validate();

      if (!this.v$.$error) {
        console.log("sankha");
      } else {
        return
      }

      // this.form.module_id = this.$route.params.id;
      this.loader_value=true
      let formData = new FormData();

    // if(this.form.prefix !== null){
    //   this.form_append.prefix = this.form.prefix
    //   // formData.append("prefix", this.form.prefix);
    // }
      this.form_append.staff_phone = this.form.staff_phone
      this.form_append.staff_email = this.form.staff_email
      this.form_append.staff_add = this.form.staff_add
      this.form_append.pro_business = this.form.pro_business
      this.form_append.pro_title = this.form.pro_title
      this.form_append.pro_function = this.form.pro_function
      this.form_append.pro_address = this.form.pro_address
      this.form_append.pro_email = this.form.pro_email
      this.form_append.pro_phone = this.form.pro_phone
      this.form_append.pro_website = this.form.pro_website
      this.form_append.image = this.form.image
      this.form_append.notes = this.form.notes


    // if(this.form.staff_phone !== null){
    //   this.form_append.staff_phone = this.form.staff_phone
    //   // formData.append("company", this.form.company);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.staff_email !== null){
    //   this.form_append.staff_email = this.form.staff_email
    //   // formData.append("designation", this.form.designation);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.staff_add !== null){
    //   this.form_append.staff_add = this.form.staff_add
    //   // formData.append("role", this.form.role);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.pro_business !== null){
    //   this.form_append.pro_business = this.form.pro_business
    //   // formData.append("site", this.form.site);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.pro_title !== null){
    //   this.form_append.pro_title = this.form.pro_title
    //   // formData.append("address_line_1", this.form.address_line_1);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.pro_function !== null){
    //   this.form_append.pro_function = this.form.pro_function
    //   // formData.append("address_line_2", this.form.address_line_2);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.pro_address !== null){
    //   this.form_append.pro_address = this.form.pro_address
    //   // formData.append("worktown", this.form.worktown);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.pro_email !== null){
    //   this.form_append.pro_email = this.form.pro_email
    //   // formData.append("product_id", this.form.product_id);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.pro_phone !== null){
    //   this.form_append.pro_phone = this.form.pro_phone
    //   // formData.append("zip_code", this.form.zip_code);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.pro_website !== null){
    //   this.form_append.pro_website = this.form.pro_website
    //   // formData.append("country", this.form.country);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.image !== null){
    //   this.form_append.image = this.form.image
    //   // formData.append("country", this.form.country);
    // }
    // else if(this.form.notes !== null){
    //   this.form_append.notes = this.form.notes
    //   // formData.append("country", this.form.country);
    // }

      // formData.append("first_name", this.state.first_name);
      // formData.append("last_name", this.state.last_name);
      // formData.append("suffix", this.state.suffix);
      // formData.append("email", this.state.email);
      // formData.append("phone", this.state.phone);
      // formData.append("dob", this.state.dob);
      this.form_append.first_name = this.state.first_name
      this.form_append.last_name = this.state.last_name
      this.form_append.suffix = this.state.suffix
      this.form_append.email = this.state.email
      this.form_append.phone = this.state.phone
      this.form_append.dob = this.state.dob
      this.form_append.module_title = this.form.module_name1

      // this.form.first_name = this.state.first_name;
      // this.form.last_name = this.state.last_name;
      // this.form.suffix = this.state.suffix;
      // this.form.email = this.state.email;
      // this.form.phone = this.state.phone;
      // this.form.dob = this.state.dob;
      

      // formData.append("first_name", this.form.first_name);
      // formData.append("last_name", this.form.last_name);
      // formData.append("suffix", this.form.suffix);
      // formData.append("email", this.form.email);
      // formData.append("phone", this.form.phone);
      // formData.append("dob", this.form.dob);
      // formData.append("type", this.form.type);
      // formData.append("json_data", data);

      // const entries = Object.entries(this.form) // 1️⃣
      // const nonEmptyOrNull = entries.filter(([key,val]) => key == String || val !== '' && val !== null) // 2️⃣
      // const output = Object.fromEntries(nonEmptyOrNull) // 3️⃣
      // console.log('output1-',output)

      // formData.append("designation", this.form.designation);
      // formData.append("role", this.form.role);
      // formData.append("type", this.form.type);
      // formData.append("site", this.form.site);
      // formData.append("address_line_1", this.form.address_line_1);
      // formData.append("address_line_2", this.form.address_line_2);
      // formData.append("street", this.form.street);
      // formData.append("worktown", this.form.worktown);
      // formData.append("zip_code", this.form.zip_code);
      // formData.append("country", this.form.country);

      // axios
      //   .post(
      //     "https://ns1.techsingularity.com/server45/dotlinker/public/api/vcard",
      //     this.form,
      //     {
      //       headers: 
      //       {
      //         Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      //       },
      //     }
      //   )
        // .
        console.log("fill form data -",this.form)
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            'vcard':this.form_append
          })
          // const data2 = JSON.stringify({
          //   'module_title':this.form.module_name1
          // })
          formData.append("json_data", data);
          // formData.append("json_data", data2);
          formData.append("product_id", this.form.product_id);
          formData.append("module_id", this.$route.params.id,);
          formData.append("portal_id", localStorage.getItem('portal_id'));
          // console.log("data hai - ",data);
          // console.log("form append  hai - ",this.form_append);
        axios.post(axios.defaults.baseURL+'usermodule', formData,
        {
          headers:
              {
                Authorization : 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
              }
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response);

          this.$router.push({
            name: "NFC",
            params: { id: localStorage.getItem("portal_id") },
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.loader_value=false
          // this.$router.push({ name: '/manageadmin'});
          console.warn("Sankhadeep", error);
        });
    },

    hide_show(msg) {
      console.log("reach");
      if (msg == 1) {
        this.after_div = true;
        this.before_div = false;
        this.contact_div = false;
        this.staff_div = false;
        this.profesional_div = false;
        this.picture_div = false;
        this.further_div = false;
      } else if (msg == 2) {
        this.after_div = false;
        this.before_div = false;
        this.contact_div = true;
        this.staff_div = false;
        this.profesional_div = false;
        this.picture_div = false;
        this.further_div = false;
      } else if (msg == 3) {
        this.after_div = false;
        this.before_div = false;
        this.contact_div = false;
        this.staff_div = true;
        this.profesional_div = false;
        this.picture_div = false;
        this.further_div = false;
      } else if (msg == 4) {
        this.after_div = false;
        this.before_div = false;
        this.contact_div = false;
        this.staff_div = false;
        this.profesional_div = true;
        this.picture_div = false;
        this.further_div = false;
      } else if (msg == 5) {
        this.after_div = false;
        this.before_div = false;
        this.contact_div = false;
        this.staff_div = false;
        this.profesional_div = false;
        this.picture_div = true;
        this.further_div = false;
      } else if (msg == 6) {
        this.after_div = false;
        this.before_div = false;
        this.contact_div = false;
        this.staff_div = false;
        this.profesional_div = false;
        this.picture_div = false;
        this.further_div = true;
      }
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (this.token == null) {
      this.$router.push("/NFC");
    }

    axios
      .get(axios.defaults.baseURL+"userscards/1",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        // this.form.product_id = res.data[0].product_id;
        console.log("response hi -",res)
        this.form.product_id = res.data[0].product_id

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    // get selected module name

    axios
      .get(
        axios.defaults.baseURL+"modules/" +
          this.$route.params.id,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.module_details = res.data;
        console.log("module response hi -",res)

        // return id;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
      });
       if(localStorage.getItem('default_lang') == "FR")
          {
            axios.get(axios.defaults.baseURL_french_language,).then((res)=>
              {
                this.translate = res.data.user[0];
                console.log("all french translate data",res.data);
                console.log(" french translate data",this.translate);
              }).catch((res) => {
                console.log(res.message);
              })
          }
          else if(localStorage.getItem('default_lang') == "SP")
          {
            axios.get(axios.defaults.baseURL_spanish_language,).then((res)=>
              {
                this.translate = res.data.user[0];
                console.log("all spanish translate data",res.data);
                console.log("spanish translate data",this.translate);
              }).catch((res) => {
                console.log(res.message);
              })
          }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing similar issue. Did you find the answer?